# Vertical and Horizontal align text link in span over background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked for a way of doing this but I have not been able to use any of the techniques for this particular problem.  Sorry if it is obvious but i am using HTML for the first time.

I have a background image on the page in case this is relevant.

Over this I have heading (h1) in a series of three spans with a transparent background, centered horizontally.

I want to use the same style for (h2) but I want to center it horizontally *and* vertically while keeping the background in the span.
At the moment I can kind of get it by adding a dummy heading (h2) in the middle and making it really big to push the (now h3) heading down.  Obviously this is not ideal.  There must be some way to just plonk it on the center but the code arrangement escapes me.

*EDIT* ... In addition, I need the text 'ENTER' to be a link.  :(

Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks.

This is the link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxLtgf80/)
This is the code...

```
 #container {text-align: center;}

          .inner {display: inline-block;
                position: relative;}

         .overflow {
             float: right;
             color: #ffffff;
             font: 100% "Arial Narrow", Arial;
             font-weight: light;
             font-style: italic;
             letter-spacing: 2px;
             background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
             background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
             padding: 1px;}

         .overflow2 {
             float: right;
             color: #ffffff;
             font: 700% "Arial Narrow", Arial;
             font-weight: light;
             font-style: italic;
             letter-spacing: 2px;
             background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
             background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
             padding: 100px;}

         .overflow3 {
             float: right;
             color: #ffffff;
             font: 265% "Arial Narrow", Arial;
             font-weight: light;
             font-style: italic;
             letter-spacing: 5px;
             background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
             background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
             padding: 1px;}

<h1>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="inner"></span>
        <span class="inner"><div class="overflow">&nbsp HeadingText nbsp</div></span>
        <span class="inner"></span>
     </div>
</h1>

<h2>
    <div id="container">
         <span class="inner"></span>
         <span class="inner"><div class="overflow2"></div></span>
         <span class="inner"></span>
    </div>
</h2>

<h3>
    <div id="container">
        <span class="inner"></span>
        <span class="inner"><div class="overflow3">&nbsp ENTER &nbsp</div></span>
        <span class="inner"></span>
    </div>
</h3>
```

Comment: Do the `overflow` classes need to have the `float: right`?

Comment: If you want the "enter" to be a link simply wrap it in an `<a>`.

Comment: Can you please add the link of this fiddle in your post so other people can test your code? https://jsfiddle.net/bxLtgf80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center something both vertically and horizontally by using absolute positioning inside of a relatively positioned element.

```
position: absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

You would use this css on the element you want centered, and use position: relative on the container element (the background image).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/94e8ezwn/1/

Note: Don't use multiple elements with the same ID. IDs are meant to be unique to an element. For #container, use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.
I used the following for the image to make it fit all screens.
Hope it doesn't cause unforeseen problems, seems to work fine.
Thanks again for your help. 

     <div class="image">
      <STYLE TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen> 
<!--
      
    BODY

          {
            background-image:url('url to media');
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            background-position:center;
          }
      
-->
      </STYLE>
      </div>